# Conditions implying image of $B$ equals kernel of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two $n \times n$ matrices $A, B$ such that $AB = 0$. Then the image of $B$ is a subspace of the kernel of $A$. However, in general they are not equal.

Under what conditions are they equal? In particular, does there exist an characterization purely in terms of the algebra of the matrices?

That is, I'm trying to avoid conditions based around properties of the associated vector spaces, such as their dimensions being equal.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{nullity}B$, or equivalently
$$\operatorname{rank}A+\operatorname{rank}B=n.$$

Comment: I was thinking this too, but it seems hard to make algebraic. I'm deliberately avoiding arguments based on the standard definition of rank (dimension of image), but I don't have much experience with other definitions.